# Plotly.py add link to local file

Tags: python, html, plot, hyperlink, plotly

I am using python and plotly (version 1.12.9), especially the offline part.

My script creates some plots and an overview table with all created plots, summarizing important values. All created files are offline plots in a folder on my local machine. I would like to open the different plot (.html) files by clicking on their name in the overview table. Therefore I followed the instructions of [add links section](https://plot.ly/python/table/#add-links).

This works correct, but only for links starting with `http://`. It seems that local links starting with `file:///` or relative links do not work. I checked the html file to avoid syntax errors, but the created link is ok.

```
<a href=\".local.html\">local</a>
```

The local links style look like links (blue color...), but it is not possible to open the file by clicking on the link. This is only possible with a leading `http://`.

```
<a href=\"http://.local.html\">local</a>
```

With the leading `http://` the same link opens a new tab with the url. Of course this results in an error.

Is there another way or workaround for creating local links with plotly?

Comment: anyupdate on this topic?

Comment: the link jumps to tables not links

Comment: I guess this documentation changed over time and this section does no longer exist. It is more than 5 years old and I could not find the actual reference, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found a bit of a workaround.  In order to get the in-table text links to work for me, I needed to thrown the files to my localhost and point to the files there, as these resolve to URLs (note: one annoyance is that the links now open in new tabs / windows, but perhaps there's a way to edit this...).  The paths then become "localhost//file.html".  In my case, I needed to tweak some things a bit on my system to get it to work nicely; these two links helped:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-an-apache-web-root-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04

[Opening HTML files on localhost (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763867/opening-html-files-on-localhost-ubuntu)